# How to mount volume for kafka through docker-compose file?

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, kafka-topic

I am using "wurstmeister/kafka" docker image with latest tag.
Whenever I tried to stop & start the kafka container, it will start container with default configuration.
How can I mount volume, so that data persists even when container stops or automatically restarts.

All data saved in logs file inside provided folder in volume, but when container restarts it doesn't load data from that folder & starts fresh copy.

I have tried following :

```
volumes:
  - /kafka:/kafka-volume
```

When container restarts, all topics should be persists as it is and with same partitions created earlier.

Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: What you have should work fine if you put the correct destination path. What's the problem?

Comment: Note: Topic data is also stored in Zookeeper container. You need a separate volume for it

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your compose file

```
services:
    kafka:
      volumes:
        - type: volume
         source: kafkalogs
         target: /path/to/folder/on/host
  volumes:
   kafkalogs:
```

Comment: All data stores in folder specified in volume in log file, but I am not able to access that whenever container restarts. It always starts a fresh copy with no data inside it.